# Let $\{A_n\}\subset \mathbb{Q}$ that is increasing with a finite upper boundary. Does $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} A_n$ exists in $\mathbb{Q}$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functional-analysis

Let {An} be a subset of Q that is increasing with a finite upper bound. Can we conclude that:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}A_n$$ Exists in Q?

Why does every sequence that is a subset of R with those same conditions converge in R while sequences that are subsets of Q with those same conditions don't necessarily converge in Q?

What I know: if An in Q then An also in R

if An is increasing and has a finite upper bound

Then L in R exists such that 
 $$\lim_{n\to\infty}A_n=L$$

So I know we can't conclude this because obviously:

$\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+1/n)^n=e$ and e isnt in Q.

But i'm not sure why if the sequence is in Q, the limit isn't always in Q but if its in R with those conditions it always converges in R?

Comment: In analysis, $\Bbb R$ is constructed _specifically_ to allow such sequences to have a limit.

Comment: I think you want $A_n$ to be a sequence, not just a subset.  But let $A_n$ be the first $n$ digits of the decimal representation of $\pi$ to see that the limit need not exist in $\Bbb Q$.  The intuition is that $\Bbb Q$ has "holes" in it, and $\Bbb R$ is constructed specifically to fill all possible holes.

Answer (score 1):

No, the decimal expansion of $\sqrt 2$ is a counterexample.

Answer (score 0):

As a topological space, $(\Bbb Q,| |)$ is not complete since not all Cauchy sequences in $\Bbb Q$ converge in $\Bbb Q$. To get a complete space, we add to $\Bbb Q$ all the limits of all convergent rational sequences.

Comment: Personally I prefer the Dedekind cut construction.  If you use limits, proving that your construction is well defined can get messy.

Comment: @RobertShore I agree that the formulation in this answer is clumsy (should say Cauchy rather than convergent in the last sentence, and equivalence classes rather than limits) but the proof that the relevant relation on Cauchy sequences is an equivalence relation is rather straightforward. In addition, the definition of addition, subtraction and multiplication of real numbers is a lot simpler than with Dedekind cuts. Division is a bit messy, but not much.